# UIViewController presentModalViewController: animated: causes SIGABRT

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I have two nib files. ViewController.xib  and NewView.xib.

From inside the viewController of the first nib when I try to execute the following code on click of a button:

```
NewView *secondView = [NewView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView.xib" bundle:nil];
secondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

a SIGABRT is sent to the program. (NewView is the second view controller)

but when I replace the first line with:

```
NewView *secondView = [NewView alloc]init];
```

it works fine and my second nib is presented as a modal view.

The file's owner is set as NewView and view is also connected to the file's owner.

I am very new to iOS and don't understand why this is happening. Please throw some light.

Comment: Try adding something like `NSLog("New View: %@", secondView)` right after you load the xib file, so we can see if secondView is actually getting loaded. I suspect it might be nil.

Comment: yup. it was not being loaded. but i didnt understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think I know what you need to do. Try replacing

```
NewView *secondView = [NewView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView.xib" bundle:nil];
```

with

```
NewView *secondView = [NewView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:nil];
```

I believe I have had this problem before, and it came down to the fact that you are NOT expected to include the extension when loading a xib file.